# Changing class dynamically with *ngIf in child component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

first, I apologize if this has been answered in some way before, I did find two close answers here:

[Question similar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmfuk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)     | [Solution Close](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmfuk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

There are three components inside of an Angular [Material Sidenav component](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples) . The containing component (red in the screenshot) has buttons that look like tabs, which when clicked load one of the three components.

```
<button (click)="onTabClick(1)"><i class="fas fa-layer-plus"></i>
<button (click)="onTabClick(2)"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-edit"></i></button>
<button (click)="onTabClick(3)"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
```

The buttons swap out components with *ngIf

```
 <app-map-features *ngIf="tabIndex === 1" [id]="'test'" ></app-map-features>
 <app-map-edit-live-data *ngIf="tabIndex === 2" [id]="'test2'" ></app-map-edit-live-data>
 <app-map-zoom *ngIf="tabIndex === 3" [className]="'other'"></app-map-zoom>
```

TS:

```
export class containingComponent implements OnInit {
  tabIndex = 1 ;    
  onTabClick(index) {
    this.tabIndex = index;
  }
```

On click, a background color is applied to the the Font-Awesome icon. This works as expected.

```
.fas:hover {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}
```

The goal is that when a certain component is showing, the .fas background color to be different in order to indicate when a certain component's content is showing.

I won't go into all of the things that I have tried because none of them have worked! What are some ways to just get the class to update when taxIndex has a certain value as true? It seems like the components aren't aware of each other.

[image: Content 1 and tabs shown]

Comment: Could you please clarify what codes associated to the red and blue rectange? sorry, a little confused

Comment: Parent and child components (red containing parent, blue child).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all your code but if I understand correctly, you want to be able to change the background color based on what component is selected. 
Since this is tied to the tab index, you can use [ngClass] on the background component and dynamically switch classes based on the tab index as follows:

HTML:

```
<!-- This is the component with the red outline in your screenshot, since I can't see your code... -->

<red-outline-component 
  [ngClass] = "{'map-features-bg': tabIndex === 1, 'map-edit-bg': tabIndex === 2, 'map-zoom-bg': tabIndex === 3}">
    ...
</red-outline-component>
```

CSS: (You don't need to provide the `color` in each class, but I do it so that I can change the color to suit the background-color for more contrast and readability).

```
.map-features-bg {
  background-color: some-color;
  color: some-color;
}

.map-edit-bg {
  background-color: some-color;
  color: some-color;
}

.map-zoom-bg {
  background-color: some-color;
  color: some-color;
}
```

[ngClass] allows us to apply classes dynamically based on the value of variables in our HTML and Component Class. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, that worked great!    One important thing, what if what I need to do is to change or reassign the value of an already existing class, not just set it?  For example,  when tabIndex===1 the css class .fas  will display a blue background instead of the commonly assigned green.

Comment: Well in that case, you're better off using [ngStyle] to overwrite the value of the current css class or using a directive that takes in the tab index and whatever you want to overwrite the color to

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, but you're missing an ending tag on your first button unless it's a typo

```
<button (click)="onTabClick(1)"><i class="fas fa-layer-plus"></i> {here}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Qarun was correct in both cases. ngClass worked (it was better than ngStyle because I am using SCSS and the color is actualy a variable. So what I didn't know that I learned through this is that I could add logic to the ngClass the same way that you can an ngIf.

```
<button (click)="onTabClick(1)"><i class="fas fa-layer-plus"
                                             [ngClass]="{'darkBackgroundClass': tabIndex === 1}"></i></button>
```